# Not understanding what linear groups are, please need help on the questions 1-4

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

Above is my math homework. I am in a linear algebra class that is the first linear algebra course i am taken and am overwhelmed with the problem.  I am not understanding what to do, but i understand the terminology. Any guidance would really be appreicated

Answer (score 1):

What to do is somewhat detailed in the wording of the exercises.

I give you some hints, hopefully you can start with it.

1. You have to check that $A,B\in GL_n(\Bbb R)$ implies $AB\in GL_n(\Bbb R)$ and $A$ is invertible with $A^{-1}\in GL_n(\Bbb R)$. For this, translate this sentence using the definition of $GL_n(\Bbb R)$ given in the exercise, and then use some properties of the determinant.
2. Can you find two matrices $A,B\in GL_n(\Bbb R)$ such that $A+B\notin GL_n(\Bbb R)$? Or, even more simply: is $0\in GL_n(\Bbb R)$?
3. Observe that the $i$th element of the $j$th row in a product matrix $BA$ is just the inner product of the $j$th row of $B$ with the $i$th column of $A$. 
   Apply it for $B=A^T$.
4. First, show that (the representing matrix) of any spatial rotation (i.e. a rotation along a line) is in $SO(3,\Bbb R)$ (that is, its columns satisfy the criterium given in 3. and its determinant is one). 
   For the converse, the characteristical polynomial of the given matrix $A\in SO(3,\Bbb R)$ is of degree $3$, so it has at least one real root, which is an eigenvalue. The axis of the rotation will be given by the corresponding eigenvector.